# C++ virtual table crash LLVM/XCode

Tags: xcode, crash, llvm

I'm getting a weird crash in the constructor of a class that hasn't changed much recently. I've trimmed away a lot of stuff, but here is the gist of it:

```
#define Accessor(PropName, Type, Default) \
    Type PropName() { Type *Member = (Type*)Props.Find(Prop##PropName); \
                        if (Member) return *Member; \
                        return Default; } \
    void PropName(Type t) { Type *Member = (Type*)Props.Find(Prop##PropName); \
                            if (Member) *Member = t; \
                            else { Props.Add(Prop##PropName, Member = new Type); \
                                    *Member = t; } \
                            OnChange(Prop##PropName); }
class GCss
{
    GHashTbl<int, void*> Props;
public:
    virtual ~GCss() {}
    virtual void OnChange(PropType p) {}
    Accessor(TextAlign, Len, Len()); // and lots of others obviously
};

class GDom : virtual public GDomI
{
public:
    virtual ~GDom() {}
    virtual bool GetVariant(const char *Name, GVariant &Value, char *Array = 0) { return false; }
    virtual bool SetVariant(const char *Name, GVariant &Value, char *Array = 0) { return false; }
};

class GLayoutCell : public GDom, public GCss
{
public:
};

class TableCell : public GLayoutCell
{
public:
    TableCell(GTableLayout *t, int Cx, int Cy)
    {
        TextAlign(AlignLeft); // this call crashes trying to call 'OnChange'
    }
};
```

It appears that the OnChange method pointer in the vtable is NULL. Now I've done a lot of things to try and check that I'm not doing something stupid. Rebuilt the code from scratch in XCode 4.5 using fairly default project settings, also tried XCode 3.x with similar results. I've tried inheriting a test object from GLayoutCell and got no crash. The crash itself is in a private framework called Lgi. It's open source so you can look at it here:
- [GDom.h](http://sourceforge.net/p/lgi/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/include/common/GDom.h)
- [GTableLayout.h](http://sourceforge.net/p/lgi/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/include/common/GTableLayout.h), [GTableLayout.cpp](http://sourceforge.net/p/lgi/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/common/Widgets/GTableLayout.cpp)
- [GCss.h](http://sourceforge.net/p/lgi/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/include/common/GCss.h), [GCss.cpp](http://sourceforge.net/p/lgi/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/common/Lgi/GCss.cpp)

I'm pretty stuck now. I don't know what to try next. Oh the stack looks like:

```
#0  0x00341880 in typeinfo for GDom ()
#1  0x00252698 in TableCell::TableCell(GTableLayout*, int, int) at /Users/matthew/Code/Lgi/trunk/src/mac/carbon/../../common/Widgets/GTableLayout.cpp:394
#2  0x0024d9cb in GTableLayout::GetCell(int, int, bool, int, int) at /Users/matthew/Code/Lgi/trunk/src/mac/carbon/../../common/Widgets/GTableLayout.cpp:1562
#3  0x0023f8eb in GProgressPane::GProgressPane() at /Users/matthew/Code/Lgi/trunk/src/mac/carbon/../../common/Widgets/GProgressDlg.cpp:129
#4  0x00241ff8 in GProgressDlg::Push() at /Users/matthew/Code/Lgi/trunk/src/mac/carbon/../../common/Widgets/GProgressDlg.cpp:407
#5  0x00241fb8 in GProgressDlg::OnCreate() at /Users/matthew/Code/Lgi/trunk/src/mac/carbon/../../common/Widgets/GProgressDlg.cpp:366
```

It seems to be doing something with the GDom class, which really has nothing to do with the GCss current class. Smells like a compiler bug to me, but I don't want to jump to conclusions. Btw Valgrind didn't turn up any corruptions.

Comment: My bet would be something is subtly changing the class definition in one file where it's being included versus how it's being understood in another file. Bugs in the macros can do this to you if you change the include order or include different headers before including the header with the class in it. This causes one piece of code to expect a vtable different from what another builds.

Comment: @david: I had a think about that and separated the class into a definition and implementation, then moved the defn up to the top of the file. So that it's defined straight after the header that defines the base class. And guess what? No crash... so now I just have to keep moving it down past the following headers / defns till it does crash and then I've isolated the rogue define. Thanks.

Comment: Ok further investigation reveals that there are two classes with the same name, one in the main App and the other is in the private framework. Somehow the compiler doesn't flag this and either bail with an error or work correctly despite.

Comment: I was sort of mostly right, kind of. (Pro tip: Use static code analysis tools like [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "answer" is that there was two classes with the same name in different binaries. One in the executable, and one in the private framework that the exe loads. Somehow the compiler/linker in XCode 4.5 can't detect that and fail to link or load the process. Visual Studio / Windows manages this fine for whatever reason.

So I renamed the class in the App and it's running fine. *sigh*

David's suggestion of using cppcheck or similar sounds like good long term advice.